# Adding ScrollViewer to Grid breaks button

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following:

```
<Button Name = "openFile" Content="Open File" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,0,100,18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="openFile_Click"/>
<ScrollViewer>
        <TextBlock Name="errMessage" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="100, 100, 100, 100" HorizontalAlignment ="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.314,2.792" Visibility="Visible" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

This breaks my button, making it unclickable. However, if I remove the scrollviewer tag, button functionality returns.

I have a TextBlock that is meant display error information. Sometimes this can grow beyond the borders of the application and I wanted to make it scrollable. How can I do that?

Comment: Don't use `Margin` or Transformations to layout elements, study up on the different [layout containers](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/introduction-to-wpf-panels/).  They will help you properly layout and size your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define the button after the `ScrollViewer` you will be able to click it. When the `ScrollViewer` is defined last you won't be able to click anything that is under it in the window.

If you add a Background color to your `ScrollViewer` you would realize that your button disappears from the window since it's behind the `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Name="errMessage" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="100, 100, 100, 100" HorizontalAlignment ="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.314,2.792" Visibility="Visible" />
</ScrollViewer>
<Button Name = "openFile" Content="Open File" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="100,0,100,18" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="openFile_Click"/>
```

Comment: Why does the order matter?

Comment: @M.Nar In the first case since the `ScrollViewer` was defined second it appears on top of the button so you couldn't click it. Now the button appears on top of the `ScrollViewer`.